# how to get the value of the PHP web service array using .NET

Tags: vb.net

The web service application is already running well if using a web application client base (PHP and NUSOAP) but I tried using VB.NET with the webservice the result is only the first array value (["error_code"]).

The client script uses PHP and the results are as follows:

```php
require "nusoap/nusoap.php";

require "nusoap/class.wsdlcache.php";

$wsdl = "http://localhost:8080/serv/product.php?wsdl";

$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);

$aproxy = $client->getProxy();

$table = “tproduct”;

$filter =””;

$result = $aproxy-> GetData ( $table, $filter);

var_dump($result);
```

Result of var_dump:

```php
array(3)
 { 

["error_code"]=> string(1) "0" 

["error_desc"]=> string(0) "" 

["result"]=> array(4) 

{
["product_id"]=> string(10) "1105201102" 

["name"]=> string(8) "Television" 

["merk"]=> string(16) "Blaupunk 28 VGC" 

["code_id"]=> string(2) "20" 

["d_created"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01 00:00:00" 

} 

}
```

The above results are correct and there are no problems.
When I use VB.NET I make it as below:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim wbsrv As New webreference.WSLOGISTIC

        MsgBox(wbsrv. GetData("tproduk",””))

    End Sub

End Class
```

The result = 0, in PHP webservice the value is the same as ["error_code"] => string (1) "0"

In the VB.NET object-browser the following results are generated (from service references);

http://localhost:8080/serv/product.php/GetData", RequestNamespace:="", ResponseNamespace:="")>  _

```
    Public Function GetData(ByVal table As String, ByVal filter As String) As <System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("output")> String

        Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("GetData", New Object() {table, filter})

        Return CType(results(0),String)

    End Function
```

I need the value of product_id and others.

I just tried VB.NET and I need help from the masters here. What should I do?...

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to inspect the HTTP traffic to spot the differences between a known working client and your own.

Comment: thank you dai, I already used fiddler, when vb.net was run, the response was as an xml document. and according to the php array structure above.           
                                                                                                                         
        the problem is I don't know where to insert the script to read data contents like product_id, name, brand, code_id, d_created.

 because after vb.net the getdata () function is executed, the result is only a 1 digit string (result (0)).

if you don't mind teaching me. Thank you very much.